# Как из базы данных sqlite3 занести name в QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, sqlite3, qlabel, qmainwindow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это тестовая версия моего окна в приложении и я не знаю как из базы данных занести Name в QLabel

Получаю ошибку:

> TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:

```
from Class_rep import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
import sys
import sqlite3

rep = Repository('E:\Запросы польз/orders.db')

class PROFIL_NEW(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PROFIL_NEW, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Профиль')
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1000,900)
        self.setStyleSheet('.PROFIL_NEW {background-image: url(profil1.jpg);}')
        self.profil_instruct()

    def profil_instruct(self):
        self.photo = QLabel('', self)
        self.photo.setGeometry(60,60,320,300)
        self.photo.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {background-image: url(photo_profil.jpg);}')

        self.lp_name = QLabel('Name:', self)
        self.lp_name.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b}')
        self.lp_name.setFont(QFont('Arial', 38, 1, True))
        self.lp_name.setGeometry(60,400,300,100)

        self.lp_Surname = QLabel('Surname:', self)
        self.lp_Surname.setGeometry(60,510,300,100)
        self.lp_Surname.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b;}')
        self.lp_Surname.setFont(QFont('Arial', 35, 1, True))

        self.lp_Age = QLabel('Age:', self)
        self.lp_Age.setGeometry(60,620,300,100)
        self.lp_Age.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b;}')
        self.lp_Age.setFont(QFont('Arial', 38, 1, True))

        self.lp_Gender = QLabel('Gender:', self)
        self.lp_Gender.setGeometry(60,730,300,100)
        self.lp_Gender.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b;}')
        self.lp_Gender.setFont(QFont('Arial', 38, 1, True))

        self.lp_id = QLabel('id:', self)
        self.lp_id.setGeometry(420,50,100,100)
        self.lp_id.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b;}')
        self.lp_id.setFont(QFont('Arial', 39, 1, True))

        self.lp_login = QLabel('login:', self)
        self.lp_login.setGeometry(420,150,200,100)
        self.lp_login.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b;}')
        self.lp_login.setFont(QFont('Arial', 37, 1, True))

        self.lp_pasword = QLabel('pasword:', self)
        self.lp_pasword.setGeometry(420,250,300,100)
        self.lp_pasword.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b;}')
        self.lp_pasword.setFont(QFont('Arial', 32, 1, True))

        self.s_loginn = input('')

        rep.cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users WHERE login = (?)""", (self.s_loginn,))
        name = rep.cur.fetchone()
        self.dt_name = QLabel(name, self)
        self.dt_name.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {color: #00b77b}')
        self.dt_name.setFont(QFont('Arial', 38, 1, True))
        self.dt_name.setGeometry(160,400,300,100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication([])
    w = PROFIL_NEW()
    w.show()
    App.exec_()
```

Comment: Может `self.dt_name.setText(name)` вам поможет?

Answer (score 1):

Забудьте про  `input('')`, виджет [**QLineEdit**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) представляет собой однострочный текстовый редактор.

Класс [**QMainWindow**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) предоставляет главное окно приложения. 
...
**Примечание**. Создание главного окна без центрального виджета не поддерживается. У вас должен быть центральный виджет, даже если это просто заполнитель.
...

и т.д.

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# ??? from Class_rep import *
# ??? rep = Repository('E:\Запросы польз/orders.db')


class ProfilNew(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProfilNew, self).__init__()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()                                # !!! +++ важно
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Профиль')
        self.resize(800, 600)
        
        self.profil_instruct()
        
        self.con = sqlite3.connect("orders.db")                                         # +++

    def profil_instruct(self):
        self.photo = QLabel()
#        self.photo.setStyleSheet('.QLabel {background-image: url(head2.jpg);}')
# +++ установите свое изображенин ------->  vvvvvvvvv
        self.photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("head2.jpg").scaled(200, 200))               # +++  
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.photo, 0, 0, 3, 2, alignment = Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.lp_name = QLabel('Name:', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lp_name, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lp_Surname = QLabel('Surname:', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lp_Surname, 4, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lp_Age = QLabel('Age:', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lp_Age, 5, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lp_Gender = QLabel('Gender:', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lp_Gender, 6, 0, 1, 1)

        self.lp_id = QLabel('id:', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lp_id, 0, 2, 1, 1)

        self.lp_login = QLabel('login:', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lp_login, 1, 2, 1, 1)

        self.lp_pasword = QLabel('pasword:', self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lp_pasword, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText='Введите логин для поиска')                                             # +++
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 7, 0, 1, 2)
        
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Поиск')                                        # +++
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.search)
        self.pushButton.setMinimumWidth(400)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 7, 2, 1, 2)        
        
        self.dt_name = QLabel()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dt_name, 3, 1, 1, 1)

    def search(self):                                                                  # +++
        s_loginn = self.lineEdit.text()
        if not s_loginn:    
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание',
                "Введите логин для поиска."
            )
            return
        cur = self.con.cursor()        
        rep = cur.execute("""SELECT name FROM users WHERE login = (?)""", (s_loginn,))

        rep = rep.fetchone() 
        if rep:
            name = rep[0]
            self.dt_name.setText(name)
        else:
            msg = QMessageBox.information(self, 
                'Внимание',
                f"Нет записи для логина {s_loginn}."
            )
        
# тут ваши стили
qss = '''
#centralwidget {
/* установите свое изображенин -->   vvvvvvvvv   */
    background-image:            url(first.jpg);
}
QLabel {
    color: #00b77b;
}
QMessageBox {
    color: #ffb77b;
}
QMessageBox QPushButton {
    font-size: 12px;
}
QMessageBox QLabel {
    color: #ff5555;
    font-size: 18px;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 32, 1, True))                            # +++  
    
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                                                    # +++  
    
    w = ProfilNew()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Artem что не так? Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour